# Swing Library for Dragging Components in Java

Tags: java, swing, draggable

I am trying to create a type of Graphics Editor that allows users to create graphic depictions of American Football plays. To do this, the User should be able to do the following:

1) Click and Move images with Left Mouse Click

2) Change images (circles, squares, and lines)

3) Reset size of all objects

Ideally, I would like to be able to add adjustable colors and line thickness, but that is far down the road.

Right now, all I can do is create JButtons that cycle through images when clicked. I think I would like to change this to JComboBox so users can go straight to the correct image. Here is my class called: FBButton

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FBButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    ImageIcon SN, SL, SR, SC, CN, CL, CR, CC, IN;
    byte value = 0;
    FBMouseListener listener;

    public FBButton() {

        listener = new FBMouseListener();

        SN = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("square_null.png"));
        SL = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("square_left.png"));
        SR = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("square_right.png"));
        SC = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("square_line.png"));

        CN = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("circle_null.png"));
        CL = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("circle_left.png"));
        CR = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("circle_right.png"));
        CC = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("circle_line.png"));

        IN = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("invisible.png"));

        addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        value++;
        value %= 9;

        if (value == 1) {
            setIcon(SN);
        } else if (value == 2) {
            setIcon(SL);
        } else if (value == 3) {
            setIcon(SR);
        } else if (value == 4) {
            setIcon(SC);
        } else if (value == 5) {
            setIcon(CN);
        } else if (value == 6) {
            setIcon(CL);
        } else if (value == 7) {
            setIcon(CR);
        } else if (value == 8) {
            setIcon(CC);
        } else {
            setIcon(IN);
        }


    }

}
```

These buttons work and the images can be found. Here is my code for the class FBPlayerFrame

```
package swing;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FBPlayerFrame extends JFrame {

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    FBButton buttons[] = new FBButton[22];
    String choices[] = { "Hallo", "Bonjour", "Conichuwa" };
    JComboBox boxes[];
    JComboBox here = new JComboBox(choices);
    FBComboBox vince;

    Dimension dim = new Dimension(52, 52);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FBPlayerFrame();
    }

    public FBPlayerFrame() {
        super("Football Start");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p.setLayout(null);


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new FBButton();
            buttons[i].setPreferredSize(dim);
            buttons[i].setLocation(20, 40 + 60 * i);
            p.add(buttons[i]);


        }


        add(p);

        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

In the spirit of keeping specific, what I am looking for first is the ability to Left Click and Drag JButtons,or JComboBoxes, throughout the frame. It would also help later if the Coordinates of the Buttons could be saved at some point, but that is not necessary now.

I have searched StackOverflow and youtube for similar questions, but have had a challenging time finding something that answers my question specifically.

**UPDATE:** Here is my code for FBMouseListener

```
package swing;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class FBMouseListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        pressed = me;
        System.out.println("Found me");
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        System.out.println("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        component.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: setBounds and repaint should be able to help you out. I remember doing something similar, making my Buttons "draggable" years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic code for dragging a component is:

```
public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
     }
}
```

You create an single instance of the class and then add it to any component you wish to drag.

```
DragListener drag = new DragListener();
component.addMouseListener( drag );
component.addMouseMotionListener( drag );
```

You can also check out the [Component Mover](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) class. It allows you to drag windows on the desktop or components in  panel. It provides a few more dragging features.

Edit:

It takes me a couple of lines of code to test this solution:

```
JButton button = new JButton("hello");
button.setSize( button.getPreferredSize() );

DragListener drag = new DragListener();
button.addMouseListener( drag );
button.addMouseMotionListener( drag );

JPanel panel = new JPanel( null );
panel.add( button );

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add( panel );
frame.setSize(400, 400);
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Put the above code in a main() method and you have simple code to test.

Comment: I am fairly new to Java. I typically have been coding in C, and OOP is still quite new to me. In fact, this is one of my first attempts at a sophisticated code. 

I created a new class called `FBDragListener` and essentially copied your code over. Then, inside of `FBButton` I added a new line like

...
`FBDragListener listener`
`public FBButton() { `
`listener = new FBDragListener()` ...

and I thought that this would make the buttons able to move. I am not getting any errors, but the program seems to function the same [the buttons are there and clickable, but cannot be moved].

Comment: Did you read the link provided? Did you add the listener to the button? Does your panel use a null layout?

Comment: I did read the link provided, thank you for that tool. I am still trying to synthesize it, but I appreciate you sourcing it for me. 

I added the listener to the button and changed the Jpanel `p` with `p.setLayout(null)` . What is odd is now my buttons aren't showing up at all, even though I use setLocation() for the buttons. 

I will edit my question to reflect the updated code.

Comment: I forgot to delete that older attempt. I just edited my post to reflect the new Mouse Listener.  

In FBPlayerFrame I set the size in the loop. The code you provided I used in the class called `FBMouseListener` which I tried adding to `FBButton`. I must have added it wrong though because I am not able to move the buttons.  

Also, once I change the layout to `null` I am no longer able to see the buttons, even though it looks like I set size and location.