# Making Swing borderless windows draggable

Tags: java, swing

This is my attempt at making this work and it works, but the window jitters around the screen while it's being moved and I could not find out what would be causing this...

I hope you can share a way to properly implement this.

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    //getting the cursor positon relative to the frame
    int x = frame.getX() + frame.getWidth() - MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
    int y = frame.getY() + frame.getHeight() - MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;              
    frame.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen() - x, e.getYOnScreen() - y);
}
```

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871969/131872. It gives some basic dragging code that allows you to drag a frame on the desktop or components on a panel.

Comment: @camickr: your duplicate answer is the #3 duplicate used to close this question, I believe

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, people say they don't like link only answers so the link above contains the bare bones dragging code along with a link to the more detailed blog entry. Also, people tend to look at the "accepted" answer instead of looking at all the answers.